# What authentication does Datanucleus JSON support for compatible JSON store

Tags: java, json, persistence, datanucleus

*I don't know why my previous question was closed. I think my question is legit*

What kind of authentication does the [Datanucleus JSON](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/json/support.html) library send over to a supported JSON datastore?

- Basic Http authentication?
- Digest Authentication?
- Or both?

I am building my own JSON datasore and I want to at least be compatible with the library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at the code would give you the answer to that. I doubt there is any authentication there currently, but check the code. No doubt it ought to be easy enough for someone to add a module to do it.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has -1 votes yet is the correct answer. Says much about Stackoverflow perhaps